# Convert curl php response to xml

Tags: php, xml, curl

Tried with php curl

```
$url=sample url;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);  
    echo($result);
```

The exact response from the url is xml. But it showing like below.

```
Opening communication link successful.Writing request to xxxxxxxxx request successful.No parameters returned from: No parameters returned from xxxxxx
```

Need to convert the response to xml.

Comment: Did you check 'view source'?

Comment: yes @ Evert . Checked. In page source its xml

Comment: Then, the output is xml already.